AdonisJS signed URLs secret key location
There's a AdonisJS application version 5.9.0 that uses signed URLs. The function exists on the http-server package and ends up calling the adonisjs-encryption sign method to sign URLs. The signing method appends a signature param to the URL passed.
This MessageVerifier class accepts a secret on its constructor which then being used on the sign and unsign methods. My question is where can I set this secret? Is it a specific file? Maybe an environment variable?
constructor(secret: string) {
    this.#cryptoKey = createHash('sha256').update(secret).digest()
}

sign(payload: any, expiresIn?: string | number, purpose?: string) {
    if (payload === null || payload === undefined) {
      throw new RuntimeException(`Cannot sign "${payload}" value`)
    }

    const encoded = base64.urlEncode(new MessageBuilder().build(payload, expiresIn, purpose))
    return `${encoded}${this.#separator}${new Hmac(this.#cryptoKey).generate(encoded)}`
  }

The following comes from the Encryption class:
 constructor(options: EncryptionOptions) {
    const secretValue =
      options.secret && typeof options.secret === 'object' && 'release' in options.secret
        ? options.secret.release()
        : options.secret

    this.#options = { algorithm: 'aes-256-cbc', ...options }
    this.#validateSecret(secretValue)
    this.#cryptoKey = createHash('sha256').update(secretValue).digest()
    this.verifier = new MessageVerifier(secretValue)
  }

According to the encryption docs page there's a config/app.ts file defining an appKey but I can't find any.
As I said it's a version 5 AdonisJS application.
I downloaded all the core packages from adonisjs and finally ended to the encryption package that contains the class accepting the secret, but I couldn't understand where's this secret is being configured.
